# why this procedure is not getting created

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter //

create procedure upd_userinput(in counts INT)     

begin      

     DECLARE m_results INT;
     DECLARE m_size INT;

CASE
WHEN counts >= 1000000 && counts < 2000000 then 
set m_size = 2621440;

else m_results =0;

end case;
```

Comment: Where is the error message

Comment: Your sample code has no `end` to match your proc's `begin`. Did you show your complete proc, or only a part?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a variable, you need to use the SET comand

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure upd_userinput(in counts INT)     

begin      

     DECLARE m_results INT;
     DECLARE m_size INT;

    case when  counts >= 1000000 AND counts < 2000000 then 
        set m_size = 2621440;
    else 
      SET m_results := 0;
    end case;  
END//
DELIMITER ;
```